# Is crowd-funding Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, riba, investment

Is it Halal to donate money to company (who need money to fund a product/project/etc...) online via crowd-funding sites such as: [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/) or [IndieGoGo](https://www.indiegogo.com/)?

What if I gave money to a company (who need money to fund a product) in order to expect something back (i.e. the finished product), would that be considered Halal?

For those who are unaware of what crowd-funding sites are, they are a platform which allow large quantities of people to give money to a company to either help fund a project, such as [this](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/onion/onion-omega-invention-platform-for-the-internet-of?ref=category_popular) (with this example, if you pay a certain amount you will receive the finished product) or to fund aid programs, such as [this](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/gorkha-district-earthquake-relief-nepal-3-vdc).

I assume that we are allowed to give money to these companies ensuring that they are Halal?

Thanks!

Comment: You are donating to the company, there isn't anything Haram about donating to companies. You won't get rewards from Allah for doing so (since its a profit company). You might still get rewards for the donation from the company itself. It is your money you can give it to whomever you want unless they are doing Haram business.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, crowd-funding is halal (as long as the target activity is halal). In fact, Muslims have been doing this for ages for building masjids, bridges, roadways and other public goods.

Even LaunchGood, one of crowd-funding sites, [self-claims](https://www.launchgood.com/faq#halal) to be halal:

> ### Are you guys halal?
>
> Yup. We're 100% certified zabiha halal :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was just wondering whether there may be something that I missed in which may contradict with Islamic guidelines. Again thank you!

Comment: [zabiha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhabihah): "the prescribed method of ritual slaughter of all lawful halal animals".

Comment: Not sure why you posted that comment @RebeccaJ.Stones , but I guess that's because of the claim of launchgood? Clearly, the "zabiha" part of that claim is a joke. They are simply trying to be funny.

Answer (score -3):

It depends on a crowdfunding platform. Take a look at this halal crowdfunding platform HalalLauncher.com https://www.halallauncher.com/ . They say that this the world's 1st and only halal multi-lingual crowdfunding platform fol raising money to bring to life halal projects.